# Why does FileReader and FileWriter use an INT variable to read and write from?

Tags: java, file, filereader

Why does FileReader and FileWriter use an `INT` variable to read and write from ?
When reading a text file,should this variable not be of type String or char ?
Why is it `INT`?

Comment: Can you give an example? Which method of `FileReader` are you referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), you will see that it provides two `read()` methods. One returns a single character as an `int` and the other reads data into a `char[]`. I assume you are asking about the first version. The reason it returns `int` rather than `char` is so that it can return -1 when the stream reaches EOF.

If you want to read other types of data, such as `String` or `double`, there are other stream classes which you can wrap around the `FileReader`.